# Limit posts with attachment inside Wordpress custom post type query

Tags: php, wordpress, attachment, custom-post-type

I´m trying to get the post thumbnail and another attached image from the last post of a custom post type (called `parceiros-e-links`).

What I got is to get all posts with images and show them... but I need to show only the last post and show it with two images (`the_post_thumbnail` and the `wp_get_attachment_image`)

Here is my current code:

```
<?php           
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'parceiros-e-links', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC' ) ); //the first loop where I filter the posts from custom post type and by date
if( $query->have_posts() ){
    while($query->have_posts()){
    $query->the_post();

        $image_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'posts_per_page' => 2, 'post_parent' => get_the_ID() ) );  //the second loop where I filter the posts with attachments and limit to two
        while( $image_query->have_posts() ) { $image_query->the_post();
                    //code below prints the two attachments: thumbnail and another one.
                if(has_post_thumbnail()){
                    the_post_thumbnail('home-parceiros');
                }
                echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_the_ID(), 'home-parceiros-foto' );
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I already spent many hours searching similar situations and trying to filter this code but I'm without ideas... Because if I limit the query's first `posts_per_page` to 1, if the most recent post doesn't has an attachment, no images will be printed!

Any clues about how to limit the number of posts with attachments inside a custom post type?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular ? This will help you out to check more than one post type.

Comment: I didnt know is_singular till now @Rikesh thank you! I've searched it on Google too but I couldn't figure out how it can help me. Would it break the query when one post is shown?

Comment: No, It won't break your loop, but you can use it to check condition to return true only if your post_type is `parceiros-e-links` && `attachment`, else it will return false.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistakes was at `the_post_thumbnail('home-parceiros');` and echo `wp_get_attachment_image( get_the_ID(), 'home-parceiros-foto' );` Read about the correct attributes given for this two functions here:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image

Here is my suggestion:

```
$query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type'         => 'parceiros-e-links',
        'posts_per_page'    => 1,
        'orderby'           => 'date',
        'order'             => 'DESC'
    )
);
if($query->have_posts()) :
    while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
        if(has_post_thumbnail()) : the_post_thumbnail(); endif;
        $args = array(
            'post_type'     => 'attachment',
            'numberposts'   => 1,
            'post_status'   => null,
            'post_parent'   => $post->ID
        );
        $attachments = get_posts( $args );
        if ( $attachments ) {
            foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
                echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'full' );
            }
        }
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Please let me know :)

Example #2 updated:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'parceiros-e-links', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC' ) ); //the first loop where I filter the posts from custom post type and by date
if( $query->have_posts() ){
    while($query->have_posts()){
    $query->the_post();

        $image_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'posts_per_page' => 2, 'post_parent' => get_the_ID() ) );  //the second loop where I filter the posts with attachments and limit to two
        while( $image_query->have_posts() ) { $image_query->the_post();
                    //code below prints the two attachments: thumbnail and another one.
                if(has_post_thumbnail()){
                    the_post_thumbnail('home-parceiros');
                }
                echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_the_ID(), 'home-parceiros-foto' );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code printed the same image twice; I would like to print the_post_thumbnail next to an image of the same post, but not the thumbnail! actually I got it with my code, but it prints all posts with images and I just need the last one. I couldnt find error on `the_post_thumbnail('home-parceiros');` and `wp_get_attachment_image( get_the_ID(), 'home-parceiros-foto' );` (Im using custom image formatting in functions.php); but thank you!

Comment: Last post? Updated my answer and added example #2, the differention is the posts_per_page value :)

Comment: The problem is that I need to always show images (i need the last post with images), so with this code it will show none if the last post doesnt have images :(

Comment: If you need to always show images, i think it will require to attach always images to posts.